# Checking whether the record inserted in Thread OnStart c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a class library, use for select the record in Ms. Access and then take the selected record to insert in SQL Server.

```
public class SyncDatabase
{
  private static SyncDatabase objs = null;
  public static SyncDatabase GetInstance
  {
    get
    {
      if (objs == null)
           objs = new SyncDatabase();

           return objs;
      }   
    }

    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0; data source=C:/Users/cheata/Desktop/TimeSheet.mdb");
   public void GetData()
   {
      con.Open();
      OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("select * from tblEmployee_TimeSheet", con);
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

      var _data = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new tblEmployee_TimeSheet
                                           {
                                              ID = row.Field<int>(0),
                                              EID = row.Field<int>(1),
                                              CheckIn = row.Field<DateTime>(2),
                                              CheckOut = row.Field<DateTime>(3),
                                              DateCheck = row.Field<DateTime>(4)
                                           }).ToList();

     con.Close();
     var context =  TimeSheetDataContext.GetInstance;

     foreach (tblEmployee_TimeSheet obj in _data)
     {
       context.Insert<tblEmployee_TimeSheet>(obj);
     }
   }
```

}

I have one window service that written with the thread, When the window is start up, MyWindowService also start.  And then it will call the thread `OnStart`.

What I want is to call `SyncDatabase` class library in my thread `OnStart`, and then check in the `OnStart` method, whether the
value that I want to insert is already exist in the record of SQL Server or not yet.

This is my thread :

```
public partial class Thread : ServiceBase
{
  public Thread()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
  {

  }

  protected override void OnStop()
  {
  }
}
```

Could any one tell me how to do that please.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: hello, why don't you instantiate your library class and call you GetData method on start method?

Comment: Yes, of course I will instantiate it, just now don't know how to check the existing record in here.

Comment: Your service is not written with the thread, the name of your service class is thread which is creating confusion in your question whether you are talking about a thread or is your service

Comment: The service is written in the solution with the thread, and I want to use `GetData()` in the thread.

Comment: `OnStart()` should perform initialization and start a thread to do the work.  It needs to return to the Service Manager fairly promptly to indicate that the service did start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a stored procedure that check existence of object insert
if it exists return -1
if not return 0

you have only to call it from in your loop

Comment: So how can I test in the  procedure, whether the record that I select from ms. access to insert in sql server is exist or not.

Comment: hi, make a stored procedure on sql server and pass argument like checkin, checkout and so on.In body of your stored procedure make a query to test (exists or select count(*) where ...)

Answer (score 1):

[OnStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.onstart.aspx) method is called when start command is sent to the service and it should be light enough to finish quickly. It is better to start a thread or timer in OnStart and return from method as quickly as possible. Coding in service is similar to coding in any other kind of application in .net. Add the reference of the assembly containing SynDataBase class and then use it same as you have used in your console or win app. You can also provide config file in service and if your code takes connection string from config, you can provide that config element in configuration file here in service project. Just a rough code to show you how to do that.Write this code in your OnStart method

```
System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
                {
                    SyncDatabase.GetInstance.DoWhatYouWant();

                });
thread.Start();
```